# R - applying function with differenct parameters to random row frequency

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a DataFrame that looks like so:

```
             DateTime wind_speed_2m   ws_80m      e_50   ws_10m
1 1980-01-01 00:00:00      5.729406 5.969776 11.800519 4.435526
2 1980-01-01 01:00:00      5.483071 5.713106 10.106499 4.244821
3 1980-01-01 02:00:00      5.107409 5.321683  7.523108 3.953995
4 1980-01-01 03:00:00      5.923226 6.171727 13.133396 4.585575
5 1980-01-01 04:00:00      5.889817 6.136917 12.903649 4.559711
6 1980-01-01 05:00:00      5.573752 5.807591 10.730101 4.315024
```

The first column is a DateTime column the second is a column that has windspeeds at 2 meters the third wind speeds at 80 meters the 4th is not relevant and the 5th has wind speeds at 10 meters.

I have the following vector of frequencies:

```
10.65 20.87  2.25  0.72  0.44  0.74  0.62  0.84  3.73 25.55 32.61  0.98
```

and the following vector of A parameters and k parameters that are associated to each frequency:

A parameters

```
7.67  6.51  2.49  1.28  1.25  1.79  1.97  1.99  3.86  9.34 10.12  1.76
```

k parameters

```
2.428 2.150 0.986 1.057 1.131 1.658 1.861 1.479 1.334 3.385 3.725 1.303
```

I have grouped my data by year using dplyr as follows:

```
f <- f %>%
    mutate(Y = year(DateTime)) %>%
    group_by(Y)
```

I have also written the following function:

```
downscale_wind <- function(A_micro, k_micro, v_rean, A_rean = 5.407803, k_rean = 2.849805){

    v_micro <- A_micro * (v_rean/A_rean)^(k_rean/k_micro)
  return(v_micro)
}

downscale_wind <- Vectorize(downscale_wind)
```

The `A_rean` and `k_rean` parameters should stay as their default values.

What I want to do but I can't is to create a new column like so:

For each group in the f `DataFrame`, so for each year:

- apply the downscale_wind function to the `ws_10m` column with this column being the `v_rean` input.
- However, for 10.65 % (the first value of the frequency vector) random rows of this group apply it using the first A value (7.67) in the A vector (as A_micro) and the first k value (2.428) in the k vector as (k_micro)
- Then for 20.87 % of random rows of the group apply it using the 2nd A value and 2nd k value
- and so on until reaching the last value of the frequency vector (0.98 %)

I would like to have all the columns unchanged, just the creation of the new column to the f `DataFrame`

Comment: What is `v_rean`

Comment: so the v_rean is the ws_10m column

Comment: can you please check my solution

Comment: the output is a dataframe f but with a new column of the values i will check yes

Comment: the function returns with a lenght equal to the length of A_params, K_params, so it is not clear, about the new column as it is not of the. same length as the params vector

Comment: no then you didn't understand what was asked

Comment: if you can update your post with the expected output, it would be great

Comment: since the rows to be chosen has to be at random as a percentage of that of the groupe i cannot provide an output

Comment: you can use `set.seed`

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how the output should be returned

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
   group_split(Y = year(DateTime)) %>% 
   map(~ {dat <- .x; map2(A_params, K_params,
         ~ downscale_wind(.x, .y, v_rean = dat$ws_10m))})
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(315550800, 315554400, 315558000, 
315561600, 315565200, 315568800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), wind_speed_2m = c(5.729406, 5.483071, 5.107409, 
5.923226, 5.889817, 5.573752), ws_80m = c(5.969776, 5.713106, 
5.321683, 6.171727, 6.136917, 5.807591), e_50 = c(11.800519, 
10.106499, 7.523108, 13.133396, 12.903649, 10.730101), ws_10m = c(4.435526, 
4.244821, 3.953995, 4.585575, 4.559711, 4.315024)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")


K_params <- c(2.428, 2.15, 0.986, 1.057, 1.131, 1.658, 1.861, 1.479, 1.334, 
3.385, 3.725, 1.303)
A_params <- c(7.67, 6.51, 2.49, 1.28, 1.25, 1.79, 1.97, 1.99, 3.86, 9.34, 
10.12, 1.76)
```